# How to remove number or text elements from all columns

Tags: r, tidyr, data-cleaning

Dataset used in this question is "Wage" from ISLR package

```
    library(ISLR)

    head(Wage)

   year age           maritl     race       education             region       jobclass         health
1 2006  18 1. Never Married 1. White    1. < HS Grad 2. Middle Atlantic  1. Industrial      1. <=Good
2 2004  24 1. Never Married 1. White 4. College Grad 2. Middle Atlantic 2. Information 2. >=Very Good
3 2003  45       2. Married 1. White 3. Some College 2. Middle Atlantic  1. Industrial      1. <=Good
  health_ins  logwage      wage
1      2. No 4.318063  75.04315
2      2. No 4.255273  70.47602
3     1. Yes 4.875061 130.98218
```

3rd column to 9th column contains unwanted characters (first element) such as 1. or 2.

How to remove all unwanted characters and numbers for all mentioned columns

Comment: Hi Tuyen, have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example and revise your question. Also have a look at http://tidyverse.org/ for your direct problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**mutate all "[1-9]. "**

```
library(dplyr)
temp <- Wage
ans <- temp %>% 
         mutate_at(3:9, funs(sub("\\d. ", "", .)))
```

**Output**

```
head(ans)

  year age        maritl  race    education          region    jobclass      health
1 2006  18 Never Married White    < HS Grad Middle Atlantic  Industrial      <=Good
2 2004  24 Never Married White College Grad Middle Atlantic Information >=Very Good
3 2003  45       Married White Some College Middle Atlantic  Industrial      <=Good
4 2003  43       Married Asian College Grad Middle Atlantic Information >=Very Good
5 2005  50      Divorced White      HS Grad Middle Atlantic Information      <=Good
6 2008  54       Married White College Grad Middle Atlantic Information >=Very Good
  health_ins  logwage      wage
1         No 4.318063  75.04315
2         No 4.255273  70.47602
3        Yes 4.875061 130.98218
4        Yes 5.041393 154.68529
5        Yes 4.318063  75.04315
6        Yes 4.845098 127.11574
```

Comment: Thanks @Chi Pak. But any other ways to remove 4.,3., or many others wuthout writing too many " mutate_at(3:9, funs(sub("1. ", "", .)))"

Comment: @Tuyen You could also do it like this: `temp %>% mutate_at(3:9, funs(sub("[12]. ", "", .)))`

Comment: Hi @ChiPak What does it mean when you put . after " " in temp %>% mutate_at(3:9, funs(sub("[12]. ", "", .)))

Comment: [piping](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/magrittr/vignettes/magrittr.html)